# Best style of toilet when there's a long run to the drain line

Tags: toilet, noise-reduction

Is there a style of toilet that does better when there is a long (mostly horizontal) run from the toilet to the vertical drain line?  It seems to clog every few months (I think there might be a corner or two in there, in addition to the long run).

As I read up on pressure-assisted toilets, they seem like a good solution except for the noise, and this is for my house, so I'm not thrilled about having any incredibly loud flush.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  The absolute best type of toilet would be a wall mounted toilet that uses an in wall tank-carrier.  Geberit is one of the best brands of carriers available and Duravit is one of the nicer brands for the actual ceramic bowl. 
This type of toilet is a “wash down” toilet which has a larger trap way.  Almost 4”.
If you are unable to go with a wall mounted toilet, you can go with a back outlet, or variable outlet toilet, which is also a wash down toilet.  Duravit also makes them.  They are not typical 12” rough floor toilets.  But they flush more vigorously.
Good luck.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

It reads like the issue is with the waste line. If that is the case, I don't know of a toilet that can resolve the issue. Pressure-assisted toilets use the pressure to help clear waste from the toilet, not the waste pipe down stream.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 pressure assist toilets. Yes, they are loud, I describe them to people as *ferocious*. Closing the lid helps. You should consider the distance to your bed. Mine is 20 feet away, it bothered me at first, but you get used to the noise.

The pressure assist will be less effective after the vent, but the momentum of the water/waste should still help clear clogs further down. I am having trouble finding an unbiased source, but this site claims they reduce the possibility of clogs downstream.

https://www.beehiveplumbing.com/what-is-a-pressure-assist-toilet-how-it-works-and-why-you-need-one/